# OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Error decoding image in FreeImageCodec::decode at

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures, ogre

I'm using **Ogre 3D 1.9**, and I'm trying to load a mesh contained in a folder pointed by the resource.cfg file. The folder contains sub-folders, that separate the .mesh files, .material files and textures. Here's the content of the **resource.cfg** file:

```
# Resources required by the sample browser and most samples.
[Essential]


# Resource locations to be added to the default path
[General]
FileSystem=media
FileSystem=media/materials/scripts
FileSystem=media/materials/textures
FileSystem=media/models
```

After this i declare and initialize the mesh, materials and textures with the following:

```
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().declareResource("ram.mesh", "Mesh", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, Ogre::NameValuePairList());
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().declareResource("char_ram_col.png", "Font", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, Ogre::NameValuePairList());
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().declareResource("char_ram_nor.png", "Font", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, Ogre::NameValuePairList());
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().declareResource("ram_skin.material", "Material", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, Ogre::NameValuePairList());
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().declareResource("ram_skin_eyelids.material", "Material", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, Ogre::NameValuePairList());
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().declareResource("ram_skin_eyes.material", "Material", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, Ogre::NameValuePairList());
Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().declareResource("ram_skin_horns.material", "Material", Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, Ogre::NameValuePairList());

Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().initialiseAllResourceGroups();
```

Then i attach the mesh to a node:

```
Ogre::Entity *entity = scene->createEntity("LocalMesh_Ent", "ram.mesh");
Ogre::SceneNode *cube = node->createChildSceneNode("ram.mesh", Ogre::Vector3(x, y, z));
cube->attachObject(entity);
```

where cube is a SceneNode previously created.

I have problem loading the texture. The code is build without any problem, but when i run it i have the following error (in the log file):

```
OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Error decoding image in FreeImageCodec::decode at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreFreeImageCodec.cpp (line 419)
```

The mesh and the materials are created correctly, if for example i comment the part regarding the texture.

Does anybody know which could be the problem ?

**Second question**: i read that the .png file has to be declared as Font, but there's also the Texture option (which doesn't work as well). Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found out the problem. The file .png containing the texture, wasn't actually a real .png file. Opening it and re-saving it with Gimp solved my problem.

It took me a while to solve this problem, since the file wasn't corrupted, considering that i could open it without any problem, with the image viewer.

I don't know what it causes this kind of problem, considering that i have just downloaded a Blender model from internet, and saved as Mesh file.